# How to use systemcalls in linux modules

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I attempted to use systemcalls such as sys_sendto when programming a kernel module. But the compiler warned me that the symbol 'sys_sendto' is undefined. I'm sure I have inculded the header file syscalls.h, so please help me and thank you.   P.S: My linux version is 2.6.32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a module to link to a symbol in the kernel like sys_sendto(), it has to be exported by the kernel. Not all system calls are exported. See [here](http://ldn.linuxfoundation.org/article/kernel-symbols-whats-available-your-module-what-isnt)

Comment: Thank you for your answser. So, is there any feasible way to use these non-exported syscall symbols in my module? If not, how can I send a packet by socket under the kernel mode?

Comment: If you control the kernels where the module will be used, you could try to patch the kernel to export it. Otherwise if your users will all use only a future version of the kernel, you could start a discussion on the kernel mailing list about exporting it in the official kernel. I am guessing neither is an option, so to hack it, look at http://www.zyztematik.com/?p=65

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-system-calls/
Here's a whole explanation on writing them and using them. They're not used by direct method calls because they have to be executed in kernel mode. The processor loads the syscall number into a register and then issues a hardware interrupt which the kernel processes and handles to execute your system call.